# USB BUB II - Misconnection and no longer uploads

Tags: ftdi

I accidentally misconnected a USB BUB II to a Arduino RBBB (atmega 328), and it no longer uploads code. Here are the symptoms, I think the BUB II is fried. I am using Ubuntu 14.10.

- Code won't upload with error `ser_recv(): programmer is not responding`
- The RBBB board will reset is I hit the button. Evidenced by the LED flashing in port 13
- Prior code runs as expected
- dmesg behaves normally upon USB connection
- When I short the Rx and Tx terminals of the BUB II, I can send instant reply messages via the Serial Monitor

Does this sound like the USB BUB II is broken? Or is is possible that some component on the RBBB board is fried?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I asked too soon. I tend to do this.

I had to switch the board configuration to Arduino Uno and it worked